# QDialog on accept return custom class object

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qdialog

I'm using qt-creator to build a little QT application.

I have a main window where I have some controls like a "new contact" button.
Pressing the button a QDialog is shown, it contains 3 line edits: name, mobile and email.

The dialog is shown through the Signal/Slot system. It works fine but I want to create a Contact object when OK is clicked and I want to give back that Contact to my main window in order to put it in a QList created in the main window code.

The approach is:
 QMainWindow   ->  new contact -> QDialog is shown

QDialog   ->  ok  -> QMainWindow

Should I pass the QList from the main window to the QDialog as argument or there is a best way?

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 1):

> Should I pass the QList from the main window to the QDialog as argument or there is a best way?

In my opinion, best would be a custom [QDialog](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qdialog.html) subclass with three [QLabel](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qlabel.html)s and 3 [QLineEdit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qlineedit.html)s.

The labels would get the following type of values:

- Label 1: name
- Label 2: mobileNumber
- Label 3: email

You would use then QLabels and QLineEdits to display them with the input coming from the user.

Then, as your program probably already does, just handle the "accept" event respectively. You could use the following method to retrieve the text entered by the end user:

> [text : QString](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qlineedit.html#text-prop)
>
> This property holds the line edit's text.
>
> Setting this property clears the selection, clears the undo/redo history, moves the cursor to the end of the line and resets the modified property to false. The text is not validated when inserted with setText().
>
> The text is truncated to maxLength() length.
>
> By default, this property contains an empty string.

Then, in the handler of the [accepted signal](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qdialog.html#accepted), you could call three accessor methods, like:

- QString name() const { return nameLineEdit->text(); }
- QString mobileNumber() const { return mobileNumberLineEdit->text(); }
- QString email() const { return emailLineEdit->text(); }

You could also store that in a dedicated structure depending on you build up your data representation, so the structure would be something like this:

```
struct Contact {
    QString name;
    QString mobileNumber;
    QString email;
};
```

and then you would have the accessor for that as follows

```
Contact contact() const;
```

Comment: Ok I tried to be brief but maybe I forgot some important details.
1) In the QDialog I have both the labels and the line edits.
2) in the button accepted handler i get the QStrings from the dialog

The problem is how to give back the 3 values to the main window because the action triggered method of the main window which opens the dialog ends as soon as the dialog is shown.

Comment: @user1638466: it depends on what you wish to do with these values. You can store them in member variables, you can access it later from the dialog itself without destructing it, just hiding, or just assigning it to another component of your mainwindow or your application, etc. You are asking too broad a question. :)

Comment: well I know... In fact I'm trying to get some help also on the QT forum, I hope to solve the problem and I will post the solution even here ;)

Comment: @user1638466: the solution is already posted for the question IMHO. I would not post answers for concerns not in the question.

Comment: @user1638466: anything left to be resolved here for your original question?

Answer (score 1):

Make a subclass of QDialog. Call Yourclass::exec() to show the dialog (exec is a function in QDialog), then afterwards Yourclass::contactDetails() to get them. contactDetails is a perfectly ordinary member function that you have to write.